# Response keep return Status code 403 instead of 200

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, request, http-status-code-403

I am trying to get **Status 200** response from my request, but keep receiving **403**

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

let options = {
  url: 'https://www.norwegian.com/en',
  headers: {
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0",
  }
};

request(options, function (err, resp, html) {
  if (!err) {
    const gatherInformation = cheerio.load(html);
    console.log(resp.statusCode);
  }
})
```

My request header according Firefox dev tools:
[image]

Comment: 403 means you don't have access to whatever you are trying to get. Could you add more context on what you are trying to do exactly ?

Comment: Exactly, I want to display a html body in a console of a page with my request

Comment: From what i could get, if you don't do a request from a valid browser, you are received with a captacha (You can use postman to test this). This is why you are getting 403 error. From there, i'm not sure how to bypass that. Maybe webscrapping is not the best choice. Does this site have a public API ?

Comment: It's an assignment to scrape some data from this page, there is not API to use

Comment: 403 with tools like Postman. Selenium with Chrome works fine.

Comment: it's a bad assignement then, [Web scrapping is against their terms of use](https://www.norwegian.com/en/booking/booking-information/legal/terms-of-use/) I agree that you are going to use this for personal use but they are still going to have measure agains this.

Comment: Thanks for a good point @Nicolas, haven't even thought about it. It's purely to test my skills and find a potential solution.